# How do you solve this sort of definite integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can someone walk me through how to do the following problem so I can attempt a few more practice problems?

If:
$$\int_{1}^{5} f(x) dx = 12  $$
and
$$\int_{4}^{5} f( x) dx = 3.6$$
find:
$$\int_{1}^{4} f( x) dx$$

Would it simply be $12 - 3.6$ ?

---

**EDIT**

If:
$$\int_{0}^{9} f(x) dx = 37  $$
and
$$\int_{0}^{9} g( x) dx = 16$$
find:
$$\int_{0}^{9} 2f(x)+3g(x) dx$$

Would this simply be: $2 \times 37 + 3 \times 16$?

Comment: Do you know any theorems or identities that relate the values of integrals of the same function with different limits?

Comment: If $a \leq c \leq b$, then $\int_a^b=\int_a^c+\int_c^b$. Use this profitably.

Comment: As you said, it is simply 12-3.6.

Comment: @MarkDominus Wow, I didn't think it would be that simple. That's why I posted it up here. I'll post a second one up so it's not a waste of a question.

Comment: Regarding the second problem: yes, that's right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the confirmation. You guys are extremely helpful here. I'm glad this resource is available, I wish I'd known about it sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using additivity of integration on intervals i.e. if $c \in [a,b]$ and

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) dx$, $\displaystyle \int_a^c f(x) dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_c^b f(x) dx$ are well- defined, then
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx$$
Hence, in your case, you have that
$$\int_1^5 f(x) dx = \int_1^4 f(x) dx + \int_4^5 f(x) dx$$
Hence, we get that
$$12 = \int_1^4 f(x) dx + 3.6$$
i.e.
$$\int_1^4 f(x) dx = 8.4$$

---

For the second problem as Brian pointed out in the comments, it follows from linearity of integration i.e. $$\int \left( a f(x) + b g(x) \right)dx = a \int f(x)dx + b \int g(x) dx$$ provided all the integrals are well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is the additive property

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_b^cf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx $$

The integral in the interval $[1,4]$ is the difference: integral in $[1,5]$ - integral $[4,5]$.